# Replace iframe URL / parameters without reloading iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe, vuejs2

I'm building a Vue JS plugin which will be loaded into several websites, these websites are Laravel, Cake PHP and Nuxt JS. I need to find and replace the source of an iFrame on the site via the loaded plugin component. Technically, I only need to find, and replace two parameters within the iFrame source, these are: `aff_id` and `sub_id`, and right now, I'm looking at replacing the whole source of the iFrame.

When the page is loaded, the iFrame source will initially be different.

I've wrote a Vue JS method which runs when a button in my plugin is clicked, it then finds an iFrame on the page with one of several potential IDs, it then searches the iFrame URL, picks out some parameters, and sets them with new values, it then loads the full new URL into the iFrame.

The Vue JS method which I've wrote is the following:

```
setTrackingData() {
      // get application form
      var applicationForm = document.getElementById('ptframe') || document.getElementById('iframe') || document.getElementById('frame')

      // construct a variable to allow us to search and set data
      var applicationFormUrl = new URL(applicationForm.src)

      // search the url
      var query_string = applicationFormUrl.search

      // search params
      var search_params = new URLSearchParams(query_string)

      // set new data on iFrame source
      search_params.set('aff_id', this.trackingID)
      search_params.set('sub_id', this.siteID)

      // change the search property of the main url
      applicationFormUrl.search = search_params.toString()

      // the new url string
      var new_url = applicationFormUrl.toString()

      // set the new source with data
      applicationForm.src = new_url
    }
```

It's pretty straightforward, all things considered. It fetches some data from `this.trackingID` and `this.siteID`, these are just a `String`.

I expect the iFrame not to reload, however, it is being reloaded. The output is correct, e.g: `http://example.com?sub_id=TEST` however the iFrame is reloaded, I understand this is expected behaviour of replacing the iFrame source.

How could I get around this problem?

Comment: Is the iframe src of same origin?

Comment: The iFrame source that is getting replaced would be the same origin, everything would be the same, except two parameters on the iFrame. @AvcS

Comment: No will the origin of the host page and iframe be the same? If both are of same origin you can access the `history` object from `iframe.contentWindow` and change the url using `replaceState` without reloading it. If they are not of same origin you will not be able to access history object

Comment: Ah right, no, they are not the same.

Comment: How do you expect to update the query parameters and not update itself? Either the iframe looks good already, and you don't need to touch the URL, or it doesn't, so you have to update it and refresh the page